# Объект с функциями. Решение задачи

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить поставленную задачу. Вот условие:
Сделайте объект с тремя функциями, каждая из которых будет принимать параметром массив с числами. Сделайте так, чтобы первая функция возвращала сумму элементов массива, вторая функция - сумму квадратов, а третья - сумму кубов. Но я что-то делаю не так, не пойму что.

Моё решение:

```js
let math = {
  sum: function(arr) {
    return sum += elem
  },
  square: function(arr) {
    return elem * elem
  },
  cube: function(arr) {
    return elem * elem * elem
  },
};
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let elem of arr) {
  arr[elem];
}
alert(math.sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
alert(math.square([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
alert(math.cube([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для суммирования массива хорошо подходит метод [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
Для возведения в степень не обязательно перемножать переменную на себя кучу раз, есть [оператор возведения в степень](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) (а в древние времена, когда его не было мы пользовались [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)).

```js
const math = {
  sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem, 0);
  },
  square(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem ** 2, 0);
  },
  cube(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem ** 3, 0);
  },
};
console.log(math.sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(math.square([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(math.cube([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: стоит добавить больше информации, а не просто блок кода, который на первый взгляд ничем не отличается от кода в вопросе. Раз уж даешь ответ для новичка :)

Comment: sidenote: `=` в `+=` не нужно, результат и так возвращается